# Движение картинки к координатам мышки в WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Мне нужно  сделать так,что бы картинка нарисованная в picturebox разворачивалась в сторону курсора и двигалась к нему,но я не представляю с помощью каких инструментов это можно реализовать. Подскажите, каким способом можно  выполнить эту задачу?

Comment: так а что вы пробовали?

Comment: @tym32167 Я еще ничего конкретного не пробовал,так как я не могу понять с чего начать. Сначала картинка должна развернуться на координаты мышки и двигаться по прямой на них. Я так понимаю тут нужен какой-то вектор ,но как их добавить и использовать  я не нашел

Comment: Если вы сами ничего пытались, смысл кому то вам что то помогать? Начинайте писать код, сделайте форму, поставьте туда картинку, поглядите, какие события мыши есть на форме, как получить координаты мыши, как повернуть картинку вашу (кстати, если это вся ваша задача, я бы поглядел в сторону WPF, а не форм), а как узнаете координаты мыши на форме и координаты картинки, там и до векторов мысль дойдет. А пока что у вас попыток нет. А если вы не пытаетесь решить вашу задачу, то нам она тем более не интересна. Мы тут помогаем тем, кто что то сам пытается сделать, а не работаем по ТЗ.

Comment: для начала - "картинка нарисованная в "PictureBox" не может куда либо повернуться, т.к. PictureBox - это штатный просмотровщик картинок, а не редактор-рисовалка. Так что рисовать придется самостоятельно, если хотите управлять этим процессом. GDI+ вам в помощь